# mongo-erlang distinct command does not work

Tags: mongodb, erlang, distinct

I'm trying to get all the distinct values of some collection, I can get the result by executing `db.$cmd.findOne({distinct: collection_name, key: some_key})` from within the shell. However, when I do:

```
mongo:do(safe, master, DbConn, some_db,
  fun() ->
    mongo:command(
      {
        distinct, some_collection,
        key, some_key
      }
    )
  end
 )
```

I always get a blank list. I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 + MongoDb 2.2.1 + Erlang R15B02.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It's the problem of bson-erlang as symbol is deprecated according to the bson specs.

See [HERE](https://github.com/lastomato/bson-erlang/commit/a6061211c611655d1e4850caba75fd9cadc8144a) for more info.

Answer (score -3):

```
mongo:do(safe, master, DbConn, some_db,
  fun() ->
    mongo:command(
    {
     'distinct'=>'some_collection',
     'key'=> 'some_key'
   }
  )
end
)
```

I am using the command in my Lithium project. It gives me the result.

```
Users::connection()->connection->command(array(
    'distinct' => 'users',
    'key' => 'status',
));
```

So the above should work for you too...